# Elegant solution to appending vector to matrix in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I've seen others post on this, but it's not clear to me if there's a better solution.  I've got a 2D NumPy array, and I'd like to append a column to it.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2., 3.],[-1., -2.]])
e = np.ones(2)
print(A)
print(e)
B = np.hstack((A,e.reshape((2,1)))) 
print(B)
```

does exactly what I want.  But is there a way to avoid this clunky use of reshape?

Comment: Do you want an efficient solution, or one that just hides all the details? What makes a solution `better`? The task is to concatenate a (2,2) and (2,) to produce a (2,3),right?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using `reshape` then you have to be appending a column of the right dimensions:

```
e = np.ones((2, 1))
B = np.hstack((A,e))
```

Note the modification to the call to `ones`. The reason you have to use reshape at the moment is that numpy does not regard an array of dimension 2 to be the same as an array of dimension (2, 1). The second is a 2D array where the size of one of the dimensions is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

My nomination for a direct solution is

```
np.concatenate((A, e[:, None]), axis=1)
```

The `[:,None]` turns `e` into a (2,1) which can be joined to the (2,2) to produce a (2,3).  Reshape does the same, but isn't as syntactically pretty.

Solutions using `hstack`, `vstack`, and `c_` do the same thing but hide one or more details.

In this case I think `column_stack` hides the most details.

```
np.column_stack((A, e))
```

Under the covers this does:

```
np.concatenate((A, np.array(e, copy=False, ndmin=2).T), axis=1)
```

That `np.array(... ndmin=2).T` is yet another way of doing the reshape.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions. I like `np.c_` which treats 1d inputs as columns (hence `c`) resulting in a concise, clutter-free, easy to read:

```
np.c_[A, e]
# array([[ 2.,  3.,  1.],
#        [-1., -2.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim B says, to `hstack` you need a `(2,1)` array. Alternatively (keeping your `e` as a one-dimensional array), `vstack` to the transpose, and take the transpose:

```
In [11]: np.vstack((A.T, e)).T
Out[11]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.,  1.],
       [-1., -2.,  1.]])
```